# SharePoint folder permissions - prevent moving folders

Tags: spfx, sharepoint-permissions, move, subfolders

we have a problem with folders that are moved by users unintenditly and lead to changes in our rolled out folder structure.

Currently we have more than 200 Site Collections with each 10 libraries and a structured bunch of folders in them. The users are permitted based on a role conecpt mapped with groups that we permit on the different libraries and folders. They should only have write permission on the lowest level which we grant on the lowest folder. Now some users from time to time unindenditly drag&drop folders into others and can't undo it themselves.

It is currently no option to write code to permit users for every single file on the designated level.
We are working on a skript for detecting changes but it is not so efficient to regularly check for unwanted changes why we wonder if there are more clever ideas.

Is there a way using SPFx to overcome the drag&drop and move/copy actions in the SPO UI but for folders only? The problem would then still persist in synced views in OneDrive...

Many thanks!
Melli